# Kendo grid - How to open popup edit window with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have custom buttons in my Kendo grid defined as

```
 columns.Template(t => t.id).ClientTemplate(
                       "<button style='margin:2px' type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-xs' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title='Izmeni' onclick=\"OpenPopUp()\"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span></button>&nbsp;" +
                       "<button style='margin:2px' type='button' style='margin-left:2px' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title='Obrisi' onclick=\"modal_xxx_edit(#: id#, 'delete')\"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign'></span></button></div>").Title("Operacije").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center;  font-weight: bold" }).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center;" }).Width(100);
```

Grid edit mode is defined as PopUp. How to open PopUp window for particular row in the grid with JavaScript?

Comment: How about this? http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/custom-command

Comment: Do you want the default kendo popup for editing a grid or do you want to have your own popup window?

Comment: I have default kendo popup...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Grid's method `editRow`. Try this code below:

**button template**

```
<button style='margin:2px' type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-xs' 
    data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='left' title='Izmeni' 
    onclick=\"OpenPopUp(this);\">
<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span></button>&nbsp;
```

Notice changes at onclick value, you have to pass current element object as parameter to your function using `this` keyword.

**javascript**

```
function OpenPopUp(e) {
    var grid = $("#grid").getKendoGrid(),
        selectedRow = $(e).closest("tr");

    grid.editRow(selectedRow);
}
```

`editRow` need grid row element as parameter to know which record is user intend to edit.

sample in [Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@diondirza/ONeSE)